# Java 8 short circuit many consecutive methods that return a boolean value

Tags: java

I'm looking for an elegant way to short circuit many consecutive methods that return a boolean value.

Ex See below for an example. Can this be streamed or implemented using lambdas?

```
public boolean outerMethod() {

    if(booleanMethod1() && booleanMethod2() && booleanMethod3() && ...) {       
        // Do work
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }

}
```

Comment: You can make anything a lambda, but that won't necessarily make it more elegant. I don't see what's wrong with what you have.

Comment: There are no consecutive `if` statements here, and this code is already short-circuited. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If your list with booleans is too long, consider joining them in a separate boolean method, concatenating the different boolean methods, giving it a descriptive name. If you choose your method names correctly, you should get more readable code.

Comment: @user207421 I have updated the question based on your feedback

Answer (score 3):

My favorite refactor if my list of `condition1 && condition2 && ... && conditionN` grows too long is usually

```
boolean theMeaningOfANDingAllConditions = condition1 
                                       && condition2 
                                       && ... 
                                       && conditionN;
if (theMeaningOfANDingAllConditions) {
    // Do work
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think "short circuit" is the word you're looking for. That has [a specific meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

If what you want to do is combine your conditions into a shorter line, combining them into a function is a common pattern.

```
if (allBooleanMethods()) {
    // Do work
} else {
    // Do something else
}

...

private boolean allBooleanMethods() {
    boolean result = booleanMethod1();
    result = result && booleanMethod2();
    result = result && booleanMethod3();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Of course, you _do_ lose the benefits of short-circuiting here, so if that's something you care about MyStackRunnethOver's answer might be better.

Comment: I don't want the next method to be called if the previous method returns false

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *could*, of course, achieve it with streams:

```
boolean result = Stream.<Supplier<Boolean>>of(
    () -> a(),
    () -> b(),
    () -> c()
)
.allMatch(Supplier::get);
```

but indeed the question is if it'll make it more elegant. I don't think so.

I would stick with the `&&`:

```
boolean result =
    aMethodName() &&
    anotherMethodName() &&
    yetAnotherMethodName() &&
    moreOfThem...

if (result) {
    ...
}
else {
    ....
}
```